# How to assign multiple value to an enum in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

How to assign multiple value to an enum in typescript ?
my enum is:

```
export enum TaxabilityType {
  Yes = 'TAXABLE',
  No = 'NON_TAXABLE',
  Unknown = 'MAYBE'
}
```

But I do not need 'Unknown' and for the value 'MAYBE' I want 'No' so I need something like:

```
  export enum TaxabilityType {
      Yes = 'TAXABLE',
      No = 'NON_TAXABLE' || 'MAYBE'

    }
```

How can I achieve it ?

Comment: Why not Having an Object instead of a Enum?

Comment: What do you want to use this for? Or better yet, _how_ do you imagine you'd use this?

Comment: It can be done if the enum is used for flags but not for strings. You can see an example of combined flags in [this article](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/enums.html#number-enums-as-flags).

Answer (score 8):

You can't.

An `enum` is a *"set of named constants."* ([source](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html))

A constant can't be two values.

Answer (score 5):

If you have to parse that enum from a datasource that has three different values you could do:

```
 export enum TaxabilityType {
  Yes = 'TAXABLE',
  No = 'NON_TAXABLE',
}

function getTaxability(taxability: "TAXABLE" | "NON_TAXABLE" | "MAYBE"): TaxabilityType {
 if(taxability === "MAYBE") return TaxabilityType.No;
 return TaxabilityType[taxability];
}
```